# Twitter API 1.1 getJson

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I want get timeline of twitter's user using method of jQuery getJSON() :

```
$.getJSON(url , function(data) { 
        console.log(data);
});
```

I generated 'url' on https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/tools/signature-generator/7804081?nid=731 and I saved it like this

```
var url =   'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?'+
            'count=2&screen_name=twitterapi&'+
            'Authorization:OAuth&'+
            'oauth_consumer_key=[here is my data],'+
            'oauth_nonce=[here is my data],'+
            'oauth_signature=[here is my data],'+
            'oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1,'+
            'oauth_timestamp=1421914866,'+
            'oauth_token=[here is my data],'+
            'oauth_version=1.0' + '?callback=?';
```

And I get

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `'Authorization:OAuth&'` be `'Authorization=OAuth&'`?

Comment: `Authorization=OAuth&` too don't work